# How to pass a file to the server side as byte code in vue js?

Tags: file, vue.js, file-upload

I am trying to pass a file that is attached from client-side to server-side. 
In order to get a file, I tried these below codes.

1)

```
var files = event.target.files; 
var file = files[0];
```

2)

```
var image = new Image();
var reader = new FileReader();
var vm = this;
reader.onload = (e) => {
  vm.image = e.target.result;
};
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

In the first one, 'file' contains only details about the file and it does not contain the file content and in the second one 'vm.image' file content is there, but it is not in byte code format. I want the file in byte code format in js which I can send in the body of an ajax call!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the `base64` of the file input:

```
const files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
const file = files[0];
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
reader.onload = () => {
     this.image = reader.result.split(',')[1];
};
```

Here is an example:

```js
document.getElementById('inputFile').addEventListener('input', function(e){
     const files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
     const file = files[0];
     const reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     reader.onload = () => {
          this.image = reader.result.split(',')[1];
          console.log(this.image)
     };
})
```

```html
<input type="file" id="inputFile"/>
```

Comment: Here I will get byte code of file with any format ( other than image formats also ) right @Majed Badawi